# Startup & shutdown scripts for Java servers

Tags: bash, java, scripts, shutdown, upstart

I am trying to design a graceful startup/shutdown script (Bash) for a Java app (JAR) that I will be deploying to my Ubuntu 14.04 server. I'm looking for a clean, Linux- and Ubuntu-friendly way of starting the server like so:

```
java -jar myapp.jar <lots off subsequent arguments>
```

And then, in the shutdown script, finding the JAR's PID, issuing a SIGSTOP to allow the app too do a graceful shutdown on its own, and then finally killing the PID when its good and ready.

I was wondering if [`upstart`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) may be a good candidate for such a use case, and if so, how? Otherwise, what are some other approaches that I might be able to take?

Answer (score 0):

SIGSTOP pauses the process, and does not do a clean shutdown. Use SIGTERM instead.

Here is a draft upstart job for a java process:

```
description "my java app"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn

exec java -jar myapp.jar <arguments>
```

that should work fairly well.